# Moodle core_course_create_courses - create a course from specific template

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I am trying to use Moodle API to create a new course from a TEMPLATE, but no luck.
Below is a code that does create a course with all the detials but no content from the TEMPLATE course.
Any idea how to achieve this?

I have a template course with ID = 9 or ShortCourseName = TEMPLATE

This is the last piece of the puzzle that makes my head spin.

```
https://DOMAIN/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=TOKEN&wsfunction=core_course_create_courses
&courses[0][fullname]=Test Full name
&courses[0][shortname]=testshortname
&courses[0][categoryid]=1
&courses[0][idnumber]=41-11
&courses[0][courseformatoptions][0][name]=TEMPLATE
&courses[0][courseformatoptions][0][value]=9
&courses[0][format]=tiles
&courses[0][startdate]=1641013490
&courses[0][enddate]=1647839103
&moodlewsrestformat=jsoncode
```

Comment: Are you using a custom course format that has special support for creating courses from templates? Moodle itself does not support such functionality, so, unless you have some custom code in place to do so, you cannot do what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I tried to skip the TILES format and kept the default topics format but the template has not been used. I also change the template course to use simple topics

Comment: I think my options are incorrect

&courses[0][courseformatoptions][0][name]=TEMPLATE
&courses[0][courseformatoptions][0][value]=

I could like to know how to create a course with API that will use a custom template course

Comment: Use `core_course_duplicate_course` instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/Adding_a_new_course#Course_templates - you can create a course from a template by using the "Upload courses" feature in the admin settings (Site admin > Courses > Upload coures), to create one or more courses via an uploaded CSV.

The code for the webservice function core_course_create_courses does not include any support for creating courses from templates - if you want such functionality, then you'll need to hire a developer to write a custom webservice function. Alternatively, you could try to find a developer to extend the existing core code and provide a patch back to Moodle core, to allow this to be supported in future versions of Moodle - there is an open ticket requesting this feature at: https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-69219 (there may be other duplicate tickets, but that's the one I found).

Answer (score 0):

Use the core_course_duplicate_course function

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can do this in two steps:

1. Create the course using one web service call (using core_course_create_courses or moodle_course_create_courses).
2. Import the course content you want from your template(s) using a second web services call to core_course_import_course.